# Where does docker-compose up keep its images?

Tags: docker-compose

I'm aware that if I change my `Dockerfile` or build directory, I'm supposed to run `docker-compose build`. This surely implies that docker-compose has some cache somewhere of its already-built images.

Where is it? How do I purge it?

I'd like to get back to a state where `docker-compose up` is forced to do the initial build steps, without me needing to remember to run `docker-compose build`.

I've run `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)` and `docker X prune` (for X in container, image, volume, network), but `docker-compose up` still refuses to run the build steps in my `Dockerfile`.

Or am I completely misunderstanding how docker-compose works?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass on additional argument (--no-cache) to skip using cache during build process.

```
    docker@default:~$ docker-compose build --help
    Build or rebuild services.

    Services are built once and then tagged as `project_service`,
    e.g. `composetest_db`. If you change a service's `Dockerfile` or the
    contents of its build directory, you can run `docker-compose build` to rebuild it.

    Usage: build [options] [--build-arg key=val...] [SERVICE...]

    Options:
        --compress              Compress the build context using gzip.
        --force-rm              Always remove intermediate containers.
        --no-cache              Do not use cache when building the image.
        --pull                  Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image.
        -m, --memory MEM        Sets memory limit for the build container.
        --build-arg key=val     Set build-time variables for services.
    docker@default:~$
```

Comment: I don't want to run `docker-compose build` at all. I want to reset my docker environment to the point where `docker-compose up` is _forced_ to rebuild the images.

Comment: in that case try `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose uses images, which you can see with `docker images`:

```
$ docker images 
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker_ubuntu                 latest              a7dc4f9bbdfb        19 hours ago        158MB
ubuntu                        16.04               0b1edfbffd27        3 weeks ago         113MB
hello-world                   latest              f2a91732366c        6 months ago        264MB
```

The docker-compose images are prefixed with (usually) the name of the directory you're running `docker-compose` in. So, for me, the `docker_ubuntu` image.

`docker image prune` thinks that the images are in use, so it doesn't prune them.

To get rid of the docker-compose image, you need to delete it explicitly:

```
docker image rm docker_ubuntu
```